# Firebase redirect all URLs to index.html

Tags: firebase, routes, firebase-hosting

I am trying to redirect all URLs to `index.html` for my SPA. My `firebase.json` below works when the URL is one directory deep e.g. `http://localhost:8000/page1` but not any deeper, e.g. `http://localhost:8000/covid19-dashboard/page1/page1a` fails to load and gives a console error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I have also tried the below but with `"source": "**/**"` and found the same results.

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "target": "project-name",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error in the browser console, that means something in your code is probably causing it, not this configuration.

Comment: @DougStevenson I think the redirect is not working because if I add another `index.html` in a folder called `page1` in my public folder, then `http://localhost:8000/page1` successfully returns this html. I am developing locally with `firebase serve -p 8000`, should redirects work in this case?

Comment: @DougStevenson I just create a new firebase project and did a new firebase init and it redirects all URLs as expected, so their is obviously a problem with my existing project but I should be able to reverse engineer it from the working example project now. So all good now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but check your `<script>` tags to see if they are relative URLs (e.g. `<script src="js/main.js">`. You need to make them absolute (e.g. `<script src="/js/main.js">`) so that they will load properly when the relative path changes for deeper links.

The error you're seeing is most likely the result of a script-loaded `.js` file not existing and therefore loading your `index.html` instead.

Comment: I had finally worked out that the problem was my static assets not redirecting, I was about to add redirect rules for them, didn't realise absolute paths would fix it, thanks so much!